# Алгоритм детектора прямых линий

Tags: c++

Есть задача - написать алгоритм детектора, который ищет прямые линии на изображении, и записывает эти линии в простом виде с параметрами, типа А(y,x) В(y, x). Где А и В - начало и конец отрезка. То есть, нужен не фильтр типа матрицы свертки и все-такое, который всего лишь подготавливает изображение, а именно алгоритм который видит прямую  линию (на идеальном изображении без шумов) и записывает ее параметры.
Где можно найти хотя бы поверхностную информацию об реализации подобных алгоритмов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227074/horizontal-line-detection-with-opencv

Comment: Bentley–Ottmann algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm

Comment: @Chorkov: Это-то тут при чем?